# Replacing sealant between fixed glass shower screen and bath

Tags: bathroom, sealant

I have a shower screen in the bath that looks similar to this:

[image]

There is a [shower screen seal](https://www.screwfix.com/p/shower-screen-seal-clear-6mm-x-1000mm/8383p) vertically between the hinged portion and the door and beneath the bottom of the door which are both working well.

Beneath the fixed glass portion though, there is a rubbery seal that's coming away from the glass & I want to replace it, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for.

It's transparent and it looks *similar* to silicon caulk, but it seems much thicker. It's all coming away in one portion. I'd hazard that it's some type of tape, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for?

I was thinking of trying to replace it with 'regular' silicon caulk but I'm worry the gap underneath the fixed glass may be too big for it.

I guess my question is — can anyone tell me what I'm looking for from my vague description? (I'll try to post a photo of the actual bathroom/sealant when I can!) I've searched for bathroom sealant/bathroom tape/trasparent rubber sealant etc. but I'm none the wiser.

---

EDIT: Adding a picture of the seal that's coming away:

[image]

Comment: How about a closeup picture of the actual problem.

Comment: @JACK yeah apologies, I wasn't able to get a picture of it yesterday. Have added a close-up now

Comment: A couple of more angles and an overall shot of _your_ shower door would help a lot. Don't worry, nobody will judge you if your shower isn't showroom pristine. If they do, who cares, it's just some stranger on the internet... ;)

Comment: @FreeMan lol, sure — I'll try to snap a few more when I get a chance and add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strip falling off looks like rubber. A U shaped rubber gasket that maybe split and is coming apart on both sides. If the glass is resting on the tub and this was supporting its weight you need to remove the door and replace the gasket.

If the wall brackets are supporting all the weight there should be a gap between the tub and the glass that you can fill with clear silicone.  It should ooze through to the other side when you inject it, then you shape it flush with the glass on both sides, no curve, and it looks like the glass is sitting on the tub.

But it should not have lips with edges on the sides of the glass like yours.  That's why I don't think yours is silicone.

Another thought if you use silicone to fill a gap between glass and tub: If you do not remove the door, it will be hard to clean the tub thoroughly under the glass.  You may in that case want to use white silicone to match the tub rather than clear.  It will still look great.  I've seen clear silicone used between adjacent panels of a glass wall, filling a gap about 6mm.  Looks great.  But with the white tub you could use white.

Comment: thanks, there is a wall bracket supporting the glass alright — similar to the stock photo, an L-shaped bracket holding the top of the glass & I think mounted to the wall along the side too. It's always been two separate pieces (one inside the bath, one outside), rather than a single piece that split. It's just coming away on one side now. I was worried that if I applied something [like this](https://www.diy.com/departments/unibond-speed-mould-resistant-clear-kitchen-bathroom-silicone-based-sanitary-sealant-300ml/1474141_BQ.prd) I may not be able to get a big enough bead to fill the gap?

Comment: Yes silicone can fill gaps much larger than yours. Can you just confirm, because it's hard to see in your picture, there is no aluminum or plastic edge to the bottom of the glass?  And there is an air gap between the glass and tub?  Also, maybe use white .. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's right air gap between the glass and tub alright and no edge at all to the bottom of the glass

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can tell you plain: It is silicone. And silicone is what you want. Not the fancy expensive silicone. You want the cheap stuff for the following reasons:

- Silicone does leave a sticky surface which will allow dirt to adhere to it.
- Silicone does not allow any water penetration at all which keeps mold from growing on it.
- Clear silicone dries very clear.
- Nothing lasts forever and silicone does not last very long at all. But, it will peel away... and most likely in one big flexible piece which is a great thing.
- Silicone is removable and will leave a clean surface behind making it easy to replace the old no longer sticky silicone with new silicone.

So have yourself some fun...

- Remove the old silicone. If you have trouble, rub it with your finger. It will come off.
- Use a blow dryer to make sure the surface is dry.
- Pump new silicone onto the bone dry surface.